# Reassign array inside another array inside a collection

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

In VBA I have an collection with items defined as this:

`MyCollection.Add Array("Key", Array()), "Key"`

So I can refer to the value or key by the index of the "Item" array.

`MyCollection.Item(1)(1) gives empty array`

`MyCollection.Item(1)(0) gives "Key"`

However when I assign my empty array to a populated array it won't change.

`MyCollection.Item(1)(1) = Array("New", "New1")`

Refering to the Item value it will still give an empty array instead of
the new.

Comment: To Update collection, first remove and then re-add the item with updated value.

Comment: @cyboashu That sounds like an answer. Could you post it as one?

Comment: Or just add a Class to the collection with two properties: `Key` and `Items`. That way you could just assign the values.

Comment: @Ambie do you know what would be better for performance?

Comment: Not for sure, no; but my gut feel is assigning values to properties of a class object would be quicker than removing and adding an array.